# Difference between “ and "

Tags: javascript, string

I'm building an angular 2 application similar to typing test. There's a text and user needs to type that out. I am comparing every typed word with the corresponding word in the text.

The word **“collection** (with the inverted comma) can't be compared as it is never equals to "collection (with inverted comma) . Couldn't find anything on google and SO.

Here's a image reference from augury.
[image]

status 1 says that these two aren't equal.

Is there any way to make them equal or do i have to replace all these instances in the text with **"**

Comment: They are two different characters and therefore will never be equal. See the different type of quotes in unicode https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html

Comment: You can try using _regular expressions_ for the comparison to deal with these characters.

Comment: abhishekkannojia thanks for the link and @K., regular expressions seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing strings having characters that should be treated as equivalent they are typically "folded" together.

On one hand there are projects like [fold-to-ascii](https://github.com/mplatt/fold-to-ascii), which I have not used, that fold quite a few similar characters.

On the other hand you can create a simple remapping yourself, say something like this, which splits the string into an array of characters, remaps each character found in the equivalence mapping and joins the result back into a string.

```js
var equivalenceMap = {
    '“': '"',
    '”': '"',
    '‘': "'",
    '’': "'"
};

function foldString(src) {
    return src.split('').map(function (c) {
        return (c in equivalenceMap) ? equivalenceMap[c] : c;
    }).join('');
}

console.log('Strings equivalent: ' + (foldString('“collection') == foldString('"collection')));
```